# Limit Question, Multivariable Function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Its given that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)=a $ exists  and that $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to0} f(x,y)=b$ also exists.

> Prove that a=b.

We've always thought that the first limit exists only if the second one does and they have to be equal to each other in that case but I really don't know how to prove it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The limit exists and is, say, $a$ iff for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that

$$|f(x,y)-a|<\frac12\varepsilon, \text{ if } |x^2+y^2|<\delta.$$

If this is true for a $b$ as well then

$$|f(x,y)-b|<\frac12\varepsilon, \text{ if } |x^2+y^2|<\delta$$
if 
$$|x^2+y^2|<\delta.$$
As far as $a$ and $b$, we can tell that

$$|b-a|=|b-f(x,y)+f(x,y)-a|\le|b-f(x,y)|+|f(x,y)-a|\le \varepsilon.$$

So, $a=b$. If this would not be the case then $|b-a|$ could not be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: Your second argument is derived from $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)$, not $\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{y\to 0} f(x,y)$

Comment: @SiXUlm: If the limit exists at $(0,0)$ then it is independent from the path $(x,y)$ takes to get to $(0,0)$. $x\rightarrow 0$ first then $y\rightarrow 0$ is one of the possible paths.